# Is it possible to use Cookies with AWS Cognito instead of localStorage (with AppSync + React)

Tags: reactjs, graph, apollo, amazon-cognito, aws-appsync

We're currently investigating using AppSync for our API surface for our web app. It integrates pretty well with other AWS services, and we really like it.

However, when setting up Cognito we noticed that it used localStorage to store the JWT. We like to avoid this as it opens up an attack vector to leak session information if we ever suffer an XSS attack or a third party library becomes compromised. We would much rather store our JWTs in secure, http-only cookies to avoid having session information accessible from Javascript. However, after a few hours of digging through docs, we can't figure out how to do this.

We're trying to set it up with the Starter project they give for react but can't seem to figure it or even if it is possible.